# jquery.autoNumeric plug-in conflict with jquery.tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, init

I’m using [autonumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) 1.8.3 on a page with 3 input text fields – each using autonumeric.  When the page loads I get the error:
**‘Uncaught autoNumeric has already been initialized. If you are trying to pass options please use the 'update' method’**

Upon more research this seems to be jquery.tools.js related.  I think the 2 plug-ins are conflicting.  Can someone advise on how to resolve conflict?

my code:

```
$('#cost').autonumeric(
  'init', {
    aSep: '',
    aSign: '$',
    vMin: '0.00',
    vMax: '9.99'
  }
);
$('#price').autonumeric( 
  'init', {
    aSep: '',
    aSign: '$',
    vMin: '0.000',
    vMax: '9.999'
  }
);
$('#quantity').autonumeric(
  'init', {
    aSep: ',',
    aSign: '$',
    vMin: '0.000',
    vMax: '9.000'
  }
);
```

Comment: Please post the HTML of your form.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is a copy paste, you've got an extra brace after your vMax lines:

```
$('#quantity').autonumeric(
 'init',
 {
  aSep: ',',
  aSign: '$',
  vMin: '0.000',
  vMax: '9.000'
                    }
 }
);
```

Pardon the ugly formatting, not sure the best way to call attention to it in a code block.

Comment: If only bold formatting could be applied to code formatting. ;)

Comment: Assuming the case issue (autonumeric vs autoNumeric) is also a copy/paste issue, I think the error lies in your HTML. Demo of your JS working at http://jsfiddle.net/sSCCQ/3/

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, it turned out to be a version/conflict issue between jquery.tools and jquery.autonumeric.

After upgrading to latest jquery.tools the problem went away :)

Thanks for the help...the jsfiddle example helped me figure out the cause.